# I have some alignment issues using Joomla K2.

Tags: html, css, joomla

In my article header section, I'm having a few alignment issues. I did a screen shot, but here is the live page:

http://www.picturemeclubbing.com/newyear/index.php/2014-01-21-01-37-46/item/19-phil-cashout-interview

Pic here:

[image]

I chose to inspect the area I wished to move and found:

```
span.itemAuthorDetailss
position: relative;
text-indent: 4px;
bottom: 20px;
```

Changing bottom: 20px to a lower number brought the text down. At least in the code inspector window. But when I made the changes in the css file, the page when haywire. On top of that, the image next to the text would not move down independently. I'm new to this coding stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
span.itemAuthorDetailss {
position: relative;
text-indent: 4px;
float: right;
}
```

Does that work? Maybe add some margin to:

```
.authorDetails {
float: left;
margin-right: 12px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Another alternative is your PMD image seems a little high - so try this:

```
.authorDetails img {
margin-top: 5px;
float: left;
}
```

.authorDetails span.itemAuthorDetailss {
position: relative;
text-indent: 4px;
float: right;
}

Put that in your custom.css style sheet:
http://www.picturemeclubbing.com/newyear/templates/yoo_moreno/css/custom.css

Comment: That didn't work out like I wanted. Did you try it from that link I posted?

Comment: I expanded on my comment above

Comment: Let me try the path you suggested. I did it in the override path.

Comment: Didn't work there either :-( Do you have google hangout by chance?

Comment: The template code is messed up. Do you have access to it / are you willing to change it? To be precise - you have a <div> inside a <span> tag. You might also want to fix the 17 errors thrown at http://validator.w3.org . As soon as the source code is clean it'll be easier to fix it. I mean it's possible to write numerous css statements to fix it, but I think it's the wrong approach to fix bad html output with css.

Comment: Yea, the people that created this K2 template were idiots. Took them over a month to do, and it still was wrong. I knew I was gonna have issues later on and now I am :( I want to fix it, but I don't have enough knowledge to do so. I do have FTP access to everything.

Comment: You should check, what template is set in the corresponding category and update your question with the code from the item.php file. It could be at  /templates/yoo_moreno/html/com_k2/templates/joo_moreno or something like that.